# Is "Blink Dog" an acceptable name?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I saw this word "Blink Dog" in a game.

Is this an acceptable usage? Can a verb been used as an adjective as in this way?

Comment: How can we know if it's acceptable when we don't even know what it refers to? But generally, anyone can name anything any way they like, assuming it is the name of something (character, level, power, move, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blink](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blink) can also be a noun:

1.
An act of shutting and opening the eyes quickly.
"he was observing her every blink"

2.
A momentary gleam of light.

Thus Blink Dog is an acceptable usage.

Comment: Like Pomegranate Aardvark. And Yoghurt Telescope.

Comment: But verbs can also modify nouns. There's nothing wrong with *catch basin* and *fly ball*.

Answer (score 0):

If it were a dog that was doing an action, then it should be a "blinking dog."

But this is a compound noun, a unique entity that is called a "blink dog."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_dog

I think it's just parlance of the game, not common usage.

Some real-world examples with similarity: breakfast, freeze-dried